# To locate points as initialization of GVF snakes

Tags: draw, points, locate

I want to detect several shapes around a reference shape. The centroids point of the reference shape is already determined. Basically the position of the surrounding shapes are almost fix in terms of angle. How do I locate points into the surrounding shapes so I use them as the initialization points of the GVF snakes. (Automatic detecting based on reference shape).

Comment: Actually roughly all edges has been determined using Canny detector. Then the initialization of points as seed of GVF snake was done manually on the reference shape. The centroids known. I want to put some points (maybe 4 points) on the second, third so on, shape so that they could be the initialization points for those shape.